# Why is the content of existing blocks not editable?

Tags: 6, blocks

I have inherited the Administration of a *Drupal 6* site with major funkiness going on. In this case I can't even figure out where to look.

There are a few dozen blocks configured and for the most part they are displaying what they are supposed to. However, a few of them are either blank or need tweaking. When I go to the block admin page, I am able to configure the blocks and bring up the `Block specific settings` tab, however the normal fields are all missing. Only `Block Title` shows up and that appears to be blank across the board.

[image: D6 Block edit form with missing fields]

Strangely enough, if I go to add a new block of my own, the form shows up correctly with all the fields.

[image: D6 New Block form with normal fields]

What could cause these fields to not be displayed for existing blocks or where would I find the content of these blocks to be edited?

Comment: Is the _New members_ block from a module or in any other way created programatically? In that case, the creator (of that block) might have excluded the functionality to make the title customizable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that the blocks that are doing this are made via [hook_block](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_block/6) and not with the block UI (ie, admin/build/block/add).  I just checked a Drupal 6 site that I did a while ago, and all of my custom blocks have this behavior.

The **Configure** link for each custom block should contain the module name that defined it, along with the delta.  For example the "Who's online" block has this for the configure link:

> admin/build/block/configure/user/3

It is defined in [user.module](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/6) and if you look at [user_block](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_block/6) you will see that the `$delta` for this is 3.

Comment: Oy. So if my URL reads `/admin/build/block/configure/views/Users-block_1` I need to hunt for something the _Views_ module is supposed to be generating? That leads to a dead end, but then again that might be why the block is blank. But if the Views module isn't generating a corresponding view that's getting exported/viewed as a block, why is there even an entry in the blocks list?

Comment: My guess would be that there is a view called "Users" that has a display called "block_1".  I am not positive about this, as I never make blocks from views.  Poke around "admin/build/views".

Comment: This appears to be the right answer for all sane cases. In my case I had to nuke some orphaned entries from the database by hand and re-create some views, but this put me on the right track for where to find what I needed. The blocks were being created by views, in which case they show up like this in the block editor.